# Nuxt - How to find the previous route?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I am able to use `this.$router.go(-1)` to redirect a user to the previous route. However, I am not able to understand how I get get the information about the previous route before redirecting.

Basically, by first reading what the previous route was, I want to make sure that the previous route was from the same domain and only then redirect to it, otherwise do something else.

Comment: I'm still looking for this solution too. Perhaps it is impossible, but who knows ... maybe I'm wrong :)

Comment: @Alexander have you tried `this.$nuxt.context.from`, also from is available in asyncData context

Answer (score 12):

in nuxt static methods where you have access to nuxt context `ex: asyncData or middlewares` :

```
asyncData({from}){
    // do something with from
}
```

but if you want to get the prev route in vue instance you can use

`this.$nuxt.context.from`

also, remember that `from` can be undefined if there wasn't any prev page in the browser history

Answer (score 7):

In your page you can add `asyncData` hook which have access to `context` object with `from` property:

```js
asyncData({ from }) {
  console.log(from);
}
```

Comment: Even if not using `asyncData` for the component: `this.$nuxt.context.from`

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by implementing the Vue Navigation guards, on the component/page.

```js
<script>
export default {
  beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    console.log(from)
    next()
  },
  data() {
    return {
      ...
      prevRoute: null,
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Or there is this guy [https://gist.github.com/zolotyx/b4e7fda234b3572fb7adaf11391f8eef#file-auth-js,](https://gist.github.com/zolotyx/b4e7fda234b3572fb7adaf11391f8eef#file-auth-js) he has made a script to help in redirecting

Comment: Does this solution work in SSR mode? I'm seeing nothing in the console when I try it…

Answer (score 3):

There is no out of the box way to get this information.

What you can do is attach a `beforeRouteEnter` as a global guard and save the route before navigating to a new route.

Then you can check to see if there is a previous route saved and execute `this.$router.go(-1)`

If you are using the router in `history` mode you could be tempted to use the `History` api that vue-router is using to get this information. But HistoryApi doesn't allow for this as this would be a huge privacy problem. You could see the entire history of the user in the current tab.

Answer (score 2):

In the [middleware] directory you can put this script [routing.js]:

```js
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
/* eslint-disable no-console */
export default function (context) {
  // current route
  console.log('route=', context.route.name)
  // previous route
  if (process.client) {
    const from = context.from
    console.log('from=', from)
  }
}
```

In [nuxt.config.js]:

```js
router: {
  ...
  middleware: 'routing'
},
```

Whenever you change the current page in the client you should see a log showing the previous page. Maybe it can help you.